# PhpWord: Change font style of a chart's data and title

Tags: php, charts, phpword

Our team is using the PhpWord library (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpWord). We use a template in which we insert the correct elements, among which are pie charts, and the data and title need to have a specific font style. However, it seems that a way to change the style of the title and data, or to write them using a preset style, is not documented in https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#chart. Is there a way to change the font style of a chart's data and title? Thank you.

```
public function createPieChart($cats,$values,$title){
    $chart = new Chart('pie',$cats,$values);
    $chart->getStyle()
        ->setTitle($title)
        ->setShowLegend(true)
        ->setLegendPosition('b')
        ->setColors($this->colors)
        ->setWidth(Converter::inchToEmu(3))
        ->setHeight(Converter::inchToEmu(3))
        ->setDataLabelOptions([
        'showCatName'=>false,
        'showVal'=>false,
        'showPercent'=>true
        ]);
    return $chart;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Perhaps you can revise the formatting of the content of your question. Also, what did you try and what was the result?

Comment: It might be helpful to see your code. I didn't see any font style settings in the chart class but there are two general settings that may be used by your generator. 

$phpWord->setDefaultFontName('Times New Roman');
$phpWord->setDefaultFontSize(12);